# When i am formatting latitude and longitude it will remove last zeros from value

Tags: android, kotlin, format, location, latitude-longitude

The function of formatting lat and long

```
fun formattLatLong(latOrLong: Double): String {
    val df = DecimalFormat("##.######")
    return df.format(latOrLong)
}
```

Function call with latitude and longitude

```
 Log.e(tag, "Location $location.latitude , $location.longitude")
 val lat = Utils.formattLatLong(latOrLong = location.latitude)
 val long = Utils.formattLatLong(latOrLong = location.longitude)
 Log.e(tag, " lat : $lat lng : $long")
```

Output:

```
Location : 23.044380,72.529783
lat : 23.04438 lng : 72.529783
```

It will remove last zero and I am getting only 5digits. I want 6digits lat long with zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below function to obtain result.

```
fun formattLatLong(latOrLong: Double): String {

    return String.format("%.6f", latOrLong);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this

```
String.format("%.6f", latOrLong)
```